# How to disable cookies for different url path

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie, jquery-cookie, httpcookie

I have a particular **cookie** that needs to be disabled on different pages.

**Example:**

```
www.forcare.com // has a cookie set over all pages
```

Now I need to disable the cookies on:

```
www.forcare.com/de/   // and
www.forcare.com/de/*
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Show us the code you are using to set/get the cookies. Once the cookie is set by the homepage it is saved, right? Are you saying you want to delete the cookie set by homepage when they visit /de/? Are you saying you need a different cookie set? Is it a cookie directive compliance thing? jQuery can get the current URL of the page, so when setting the cookie you could not simply grab the current URL and check if it matches /de/ before running?

Comment: Did not understand you right you asked a question :p when i paste the code it doenst work right. So here is the link where the [cookie.js](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/1895870/forcare_redesign/assets/js/cookieakkoord.js) is stored. When people come directly to the .com/de page they don't have to accept the cookie. When they directly come the .com/de site it is because its IP location based.